# Dict: Accessing Multiple Values ( Orig: Display 5 Django lists in one table)

Tags: django

I decided to use a dictionary instead of list for getting the grades per quarter of a subject. I was able to add values for each key in my dict, however I am having hard time accessing the values.

My dict code so far:

```
for sg in x.subjectgrade_set.all():
...:     if sg.status == 'approved':
...:         for component in sg.subject_schedule.component_set.all():
...:             if component.is_root:
...:                 try:
...:                     grade = sg.grade_set.get(component=component)
...:                     if component.name == '1st Quarter':
...:                         y[sg.subject.name] = [grade.grade]
...:                     elif component.name == '2nd Quarter':
...:                         y[sg.subject.name] = [y[sg.subject.name], grade.grade]
...:                     elif component.name == '3rd Quarter':
...:                         y[sg.subject.name] = [y[sg.subject.name], grade.grade]
...:                     elif component.name == '4th Quarter':
...:                         y[sg.subject.name] = [y[sg.subject.name], grade.grade]
...:                 except:
...:                     pass
```

Output

```
    {u's1': [[[[Decimal('72.00')], Decimal('74.00')], Decimal('79.00')],
  Decimal('83.00')],
 u's2': [[[[Decimal('60.00')], Decimal('60.00')], Decimal('60.00')],
  Decimal('60.00')],
 u's3': [[[[Decimal('64.00')], Decimal('64.00')], Decimal('64.00')],
Decimal('64.00')],
 u's4': [[[[Decimal('93.00')], Decimal('93.00')], Decimal('93.00')],
  Decimal('93.00')],
 u's5': [[[[Decimal('64.00')], Decimal('62.00')], Decimal('64.00')],
  Decimal('65.00')],
 u's6': [[[[Decimal('75.00')],
    Decimal('75.00')],
   Decimal('75.00')],
  Decimal('75.00')]}
```

I tried to put each grade per quarter in a list then assign it to my existing key then display them in my html. If I try to run the code below, if gives me the grades from 1st grading to 3rd grading as well as the 1st Character of the subject name:

```
for i in y.iteritems():
...:     for o in i:
...:         print o[0]
```

What's the best approach to do this?

TIA

Comment: If you want to print `td` for each grade, you need to write the for loop outside the `td` e.g. `{% for grade in quarter_grades.0 %}<td>{{grade}}</td> {% endfor %}`

Comment: Yes, I did that. Problem is quarter_grades.0 is a list of first grading grades for all subjects. It displays all data inside the list.

Comment: Can you please post the structures of `object_list` and `quarter_grades`? How to get the grades of a particular subject?

Comment: zip the lists in your view. `list(zip(object_list,*quarter_grades,final_grade_list))`. Then you can loop through the zipped list. Each loop will have your 6 values per row.

Comment: Hi, object_list is in my template. Also, shall I zip the return value of the function for getting the quarter grades?

Comment: One more thing, can you post your current output and expected html table?

Comment: I would rather like to see the model. Show me your data structures and their relationships, and the code should be obvious.

Comment: I decided to use a dictionary instead. I was able to add the quarter grades per subject(key). Right now, I'm just encountering the problem on displaying the grades per column since they return as well as list.

Comment: I updated the post, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve the issue by playing around with the codes in shell_plus

```
 {% for key, val in grades_dict.iteritems %}
             <tr>
              <td>{{key}}</td>
              <td>{{val.0.0.0.0.0}}</td>
              <td>{{val.0.0.0.1}}</td>
              <td>{{val.0.0.1}}</td>
              <td>{{val.0.1}}</td>
              <td>{{val.1}}</td>
            </tr>
 {% endfor %}
```